# Why does > not redirect output to text file

Tags: bash, unix

I run the following command in shell:

```
sh myscript.sh > test.txt
```

The output is displayed on shell. I was expecting that the output would be put into `test.txt`.

Comment: How is your script? `>` is redirecting the stdout to `test.txt`, but stderr will appear in your screen. For example if you have `ls alsjdfasjdfakls` (a not existing file) you will `get ls: cannot access alsjdfasjdfakls: No such file or directory` when running `sh myscript.sh > test.txt`

Answer (score 3):

The output isn't displayed on the shell, instead it's the `STDERR` that's displayed on the shell.

If you want both the `STDOUT` and `STDERR` to be redirected to the log file, say:

```
sh myscript.sh > test.txt 2>&1
```

Since you've tagged the question [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you could also say:

```
bash myscript.sh >& test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Printed output maybe be standard error output.

Using following, you can also redirect standard error (file descriptor `2`):

```
sh myscript.sh > test.txt 2>&1
```

In bash, you can also use following forms:

```
sh myscript.sh &> test.txt  # This is preferred according to bash(1).

sh myscript.sh >& test.txt
```